# How to check if an instance of a class exists

Tags: delphi

I have a `TComboBox` that I create dynamically. I have a separate procedure that uses the items in a `TStringList` of this dynamic component. How can I test if the component or instance already exists?

Please provide a code example in your answer. Thanks!

```
private //private of form
 var
  cbxSortProfession : TComboBox;
  
 procedure cbxSortProfessionChange(Sender: TObject);
```

```
procedure SOME_PROCEDURE;
begin
    cbxSortProfession := TComboBox.Create();

    with cbxSortProfession do
    begin
      Parent := pnlSort;
      OnChange := cbxSortProfessionChange;
      left := 24;
      top := 232;
      width := 145;
      height := 21;
    end;
end;
```

Comment: Please provide the code with how you create that `TComboBox`, because if you're assigning that instance to a variable (very likely) you already have your answer. And if you even connect it to a `TForm` (which then owns it) you have even more of an answer.

Comment: @AmigoJack My apologies. I have added the code. Both things you mention are true.

Comment: Before `cbxSortProfession := TComboBox.Create()`, `Assigned(cbxSortProfession)` is `False`. After, it is `True`.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Thank you. So I could just use the Assigned function in an if statement?

Comment: In general, you can't tell whether instances of a class exist unless they are recorded in a container of some sort, e.g. an owning component such as a TForm or TComponent - see the FindComponent method - or if you manually record them yourself e.g. in the class's constructor (but this can involve a lot of overhead if there are large numbers of instances).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the Assigned function in an if statement, but be sure to set the variable to nil when you destroy the instance.

Note that when you create the instance, you can pass the form as owner argument. If you do, when the instance will be destroyed, the form's [notification procedure](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/Vcl.Forms.TCustomForm.Notification) will be called. You should override it and from there you can set the variable to nil.

Note that the `notification` procedure is called for constructor and destructor for each component that is owned by the form so you much check for yours.

I created demo code for the `notification` procedure:

```
unit NotificationDemoMain;

interface

uses
    Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages,
    System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes,
    Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls,
    Vcl.ExtCtrls;

type
    TForm2 = class(TForm)
        CreateComboBoxButton: TButton;
        SortPanel: TPanel;
        Memo1: TMemo;
        FreeComboBoxButton: TButton;
        CheckComboBoxButton: TButton;
        procedure CheckComboBoxButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
        procedure CreateComboBoxButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
        procedure FreeComboBoxButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
    private
        FSortProfessionComboBox : TComboBox;
        procedure SortProfessionChange(Sender : TObject);
    protected
        procedure Notification(AComponent : TComponent;
                               Operation  : TOperation); override;
    end;

var
    Form2: TForm2;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm2.CheckComboBoxButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
    if Assigned(FSortProfessionComboBox) then
        Memo1.Lines.Add('ComboBox is Assigned')
    else
        Memo1.Lines.Add('ComboBox doesn''t exists');
end;

procedure TForm2.CreateComboBoxButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
    Memo1.Lines.Add('Create ComboBox');
    FSortProfessionComboBox := TComboBox.Create(Self);
    FSortProfessionComboBox.Parent := SortPanel;
    FSortProfessionComboBox.SetBounds(20, 20, 150, 21);
    FSortProfessionComboBox.Items.Add('Item 1');
    FSortProfessionComboBox.Items.Add('Item 2');
    FSortProfessionComboBox.Items.Add('Item 3');
    FSortProfessionComboBox.OnChange := SortProfessionChange;
end;

procedure TForm2.FreeComboBoxButtonClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
    FSortProfessionComboBox.Free;
    Memo1.Lines.Add('Free ComboBox');
end;

procedure TForm2.Notification(AComponent: TComponent; Operation: TOperation);
begin
    if Operation = opRemove then begin
        if (AComponent = FSortProfessionComboBox)  then
            FSortProfessionComboBox := nil;
    end;

    inherited;
end;

procedure TForm2.SortProfessionChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
    Memo1.Lines.Add('SortProfessionChange');
end;

end.
```